# How to check if a column value contains integers

Tags: mysql

We have a varchar(255) column and some values are integers, how do I isolate only the rows which contain integer values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
select *
from table
where column
regexp '^\-?[1-9][0-9]*$'
```

EDIT: thanks Alma Do for pointing out that my solution did not consider signed integers and leading zeroes! Also his solution is much more performant than using regular expressions.

Comment: What about signed integers? What about leading zeros?

Comment: You're right, this was a quick solution that does not consider those cases. Your answer will be better for that!

Comment: Well, SO is not for quick answers.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up and for the constructive criticism. I'll use the edit function to further amend my quick answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [`CAST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast):

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE CAST(col AS SIGNED)=col
```

You *can* use `REGEXP()` for your issue, but I will not recommend that: for large tables `CAST()` will be extremely faster. Compare:

```
mysql> select benchmark(1E7, '17453454.6655744' REGEXP '^[0-9]+$');
+------------------------------------------------------+
| benchmark(1E7, '17453454.6655744' REGEXP '^[0-9]+$') |
+------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                    0 |
+------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (17.59 sec)
```

With:

```
mysql> select benchmark(1E7, CAST('17453454.6655744' AS SIGNED)='17453454.6655744');
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| benchmark(1E7, CAST('17453454.6655744' AS SIGNED)='17453454.6655744') |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                     0 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.36 sec)
```

-and see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Here col means, will have to provide column name which has to be checked that having intergers or not ..?

SELECT * FROM t WHERE CAST(col AS SIGNED)=col